# Python query: how can I sort on a different variable than the filter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter

I have an event website with a query that should pick all the events that take place today or later. The problem is that some events take more than 1 day, so what I want the query to do is "pick all events with end date (until_date) equal to or later than today, and sort them by start date (from_date)".

Unfortunately when I do this, I get an error saying "First ordering property must be the same as inequality filter property, if specified for this query; received from_date, expected until_date". However sorting by until_date is gives a bad result.

Currently I run the code as below, but this means that an event that started yesterday and ends tommorrow is not shown in the list. Is there any way around this?

Best,
Vincent

```
class Event(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    url = db.LinkProperty()
    in_city = db.StringProperty()
    in_country = db.StringProperty()
    from_date = db.DateProperty()
    until_date = db.DateProperty()
    register_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class EventsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        events = Event.all()
        events.filter("from_date >=", datetime.date.today())
        events.order("from_date")
        template_values = {
            'events': events,
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/events.html', template_values))
```

Comment: You should at least mention the ORM you use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using Google App Engine, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty vital information. Now people who know GAE can find your question and answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception indicates, it's not possible to do this. You should either query for each day, sorted by start date (using a DateProperty so you can do an equality filter on end date), or do your query without the sort and sort the results in memory.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to give it a try by sorting it in the memory. Thanks a lot for your answer!